# Circle and Rectangle intersection code is not working?

Tags: java, geometry, collision-detection, bounds

Why is my code not detecting that the circle and rectangle has intersected?

```
public static boolean RectCircleColliding(Circle circle, Rectangle rect)
{  
    double distX = Math.abs(circle.getCenterX() - rect.getX() - rect.getWidth()/2);
    double distY = Math.abs(circle.getCenterY() - rect.getY() - rect.getHeight()/2); 

    if (distX > rect.getWidth()/2 + circle.getRadius())
        return false;
    if (distY > rect.getHeight()/2 + circle.getRadius())
        return false;

    if (distX <= rect.getWidth()/2)
        return true;
    if (distY <= rect.getHeight()/2) 
        return true;

    double dx = distX - rect.getWidth()/2;
    double dy = distY - rect.getHeight()/2; 

    return dx*dx + dy*dy <= (circle.getRadius()*circle.getRadius());
}
```

I use the following circle and rectangle coordinates:

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(7, 12, 2, 6);

Circle ball = new Circle(5, 7, 4.123);
```

Comment: In which situation is it not working correcly? Provide inputs (your circle and rectangle), expected output and output that you're getting instead, and your own analysis so far.

Comment: for my rectangle I use: upper left corner (7,12), width=6 and height = 2
circle has its center at (5,7) and radius=4.123
expected output: true (should overlap)
output: false (do not overlap)

Comment: Your solution is in fact incredibly close - you only have to change two lines in the second pair of if-statements (they are currently breaking your algorithm).

Comment: Ehh no, your code is correct and your expectation is false. A circle at 5,7 with radius 4.123 does not overlap a rectangle at 7,12 width=2, height = 6 (like your code says) and neither if the width=6 and the height = 2. This image shows what your setup looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzaqW.png

Comment: Although this if-statement is certainly incorrect: `if (distX <= rect.getWidth()/2)
        return true;`. What if the distX is zero, but distY is one million? that doesn't make the circle and the rectangle overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You work with "distances" twice and introduce mistakes. Conditions might be simplified (replace `rect.center` with your data):

```
dx = Max(Math.abs((circle.getCenterX() - rect.center.x) - rect.width / 2, 0);
dy = Max(Math.abs(circle.getCenterY() - rect.center.y) - rect.height / 2, 0);
return dx * dx + dy * dy <= (circle.getRadius()*circle.getRadius());
```

Comment: I found the solution, I used max Y instead of min Y. this means I used the left upper corner of the rectangle instead of the left lower corner

Comment: @Janine Solution should not depend on specific corner and rectange orientation. You can get centerY as (Y1+Y2)/2